# How to remove special characters to be get inserted into mysql database in php

Tags: php, string

I have a textfield and if any special characters are attached to the string the value should not be inserted into the database. How can this be achieved in php? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
 if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()"}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $i)) {
  echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
  echo 'alert("Enter a valid Insurance Type.")'; echo '</script>'; 
}
```

Comment: Define "special characters". Also, define the reason why they shouldn't be inserted. Is it because you think DB can't handle them? Is it because you consider them to be noise as a part of your business logic?

Comment: This is my code, here the script is working but the value still gets inserted to the database

if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()"}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $i))
{
 

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Enter a valid Insurance Type.")';

echo '</script>';
}

Comment: And have you tried some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "special" you mean non alpha-numeric, you could do something like this to strip out those characters before inserting them:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", "", $your_string);
```

Otherwise you could just check if the string is alpha-numeric, and only insert the record if it is:

```
if (ctype_alnum($your_string)) {
    // Do your MySQL insert
}
```